# How to change a clear case login details in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, clearcase

Currently I'm using **Clearcase** integrated to my eclipse.For the very first activity, I've given my Clearcase login credentials. And after that, Whenever I do a checkout , it will automatically prompt me to the clearcase checkout page without a login promt.
But now I'm in a situation to change the login details, since one of my colleague is going to use that system.

Kindly provide me a solution to change the **clearcase** login details in eclipse.

Comment: What version of ClearCase, eclipse OS and ClearCase plugin are you using?

Answer (score 0):

For this issue, I have restarted my system and after that when I opened eclipse and tried to do a checkout, it prompted me for the new set of credentials.